# IF,UNION statements in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, union

I have to tables  XY and XZ that have X,Y,Z columns.I can join them like this:

```
    SELECT XY.*,XZ.Z
    FROM XY
    INNER JOIN XZ
    ON XY.X = XZ.X
```

But if occurs some condition (for example X = 0) I want take data not only from XZ table but also from another query(function,table) that has X,Z columns.I know about UNION,but I dont know how to use it and write IF statement in this case.I mean something like this(forgive me this abstract syntax I want only correct explain problem):

```
    SELECT XY.*,XZ.Z
    FROM XY
    INNER JOIN IF(X = 0)XZ ELSE (XZ UNION SOME_TABLE)
    ON XY.X = XZ.X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a lot of assumptions on data inside XZ and SOME_TABLE.

```
SELECT
    XY.*,
    CASE WHEN XZ.Z = 0 THEN ST.Z
         ELSE XZ.Z
    END
FROM XY INNER JOIN XZ ON ON XY.X = XZ.X
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SOME_TABLE ST ON XY.X = ST.X
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT XY.*, AT.*, XZ.Z
FROM XY
INNER JOIN XZ
ON XY.X = XZ.X
LEFT JOIN another_table AT
ON AT.X = XY.X AND XY.X = 0
```